# Angular: $setPristine on Form and Checkbox Issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, forms, checkbox

I've got a form that doesn't allow you to check checkboxes on the first entry, which is very weird. It's almost like it doesn't register the click.

If however, you submit the form and try and check the same checkboxes after submitting the first form, it allows you to check the checkboxes. Why is this?

This is what my checkboxes look like:

```
<label ng-repeat="sector in sectors" for="{{sector}}">
  <input type="checkbox" id="{{sector}}" value="{{sector}}" ng-model="newService.sectors[sector]">{{sector}}
</label>
```

I'm also trying to work out how to implement `$setPristine` on this form so it gives the form a class of `.ng-pristine` when submitted.

I'm very new to Angular and am slowly trying to understand how this all works.

I've set up a Fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/nh63w6e0/2/

Any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Comment: The fiddle is loading Angular twice, once from the "Frameworks and Extensions" menu and once from the "External Resources". Remove one and it works, regarding the "uncheckable" checkboxes.

Comment: @NikosParaskevopoulos I've removed the External Resources Angular include, but checkboxes still aren't working. http://jsfiddle.net/nh63w6e0/5/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**The Problem**

Using your JSFiddle example, if you look at the console while clicking in the checkbox, you'll see the error:

> Cannot set property 'health' of undefined

That's because $scope.newService wasn't created, and you were trying to do something equivalent to `$scope.newService['health'] = true` while checking the checkbox. So, as you can see, $scope.newService was undefined.

**The Solution**

You should add a call to `resetCreateForm` to initialize your `$scope.newService` property.

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nh63w6e0/8/) (check out the last line, with the comment)

Edit:

Addressing your need to use the $setPristine, you could check this [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nh63w6e0/13/) out.

All you have to do is add the `name` attribute on the form and call it as a $scope property by its name. Then you call the `$setPristine()` on the form property.

Comment: Ahh, I thought having `$scope.createService = createService` would initialise `resetCreateForm` which is inside it. Am I wrong? Also, do you know how I would go about using `$setPristine` on this form when it's reset? Thanks for the Fiddle.

Comment: The `$scope.createService = createService` is only assigning to the `$scope.createService` property a reference to the local function `createService`. It won't *execute* the function, so the call `resetCreateForm()` inside of `createService` won't happen.

Comment: And I didn't understand your question about the $setPristine, if you could try again in other words.

Comment: Sorry if I didn't explain properly. I'm trying to work out how to `$setPristine` on this form when it's been submitted. The form has a class of `.ng-pristine` when I load the page, but once I check a checkbox the class changes to `.ng-dirty`. I was trying to work out how to set the form to its pristine state with `$setPristine`. I hope that makes sense. Oh! And thank you for a well-described answer. Marked!

Comment: Ahh, that makes sense. Also, I didn't realise you could call a `{{$pristine}}` expression to check whether the form was pristine or not. Thanks for this. Majorly helpful.